# Problems with context when trying to display Toast

Tags: java, android, toast, android-context

I try to display a Toast inside a AsyncTask. 
This first piece of code is placed in an activity that we may call `MyActivity`, and works fine:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Then I create a new instance of `MyObject` and calls `method()`. This code is also placed in `MyActivity`.

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject(this);
obj.method();
```

This is the definition of `MyObject`. The ProgressDialog works fine, but no toast is showed.

```
public class MyObject {
   Context cxt;

   public MyObject(Context cxt) {
      this.cxt = cxt;
   }

   public void method() {
      new MyAsyncTask().execute();
   }

   private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Boolean> {
      protected void onPreExecute() {
         Toast.makeText(cxt, "Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // works fine
    }

        protected Boolean doInBackground(Object... params) {
           Looper.prepare();
           Toast.makeText(cxt, "Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); // doesn't work
        }
   }
}
```

I believed I was doing exactly the same thing in my first example and below, but appearently, I'm missing something. I've also tried `getApplicationContext()` and `cxt.getApplicationContext()` instead of `cxt`, but with the same result.

Comment: You should NOT be creating new instances of activities with `new`

Comment: Sorry, I don't do that normally. I just re-wrote my regular code into a better example and didn't think about it. But thanks for the point! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap that into the `runOnUIThread` method:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(cxt, "Toast!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

That's because the `doInBackground` method is not executed on the UI Thread, so you have to force that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use

```
MyObject.this
```

inside of the AsyncTask